# Updating ListView invokes Null Pointer Exception on ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

Trying to update a listview from an ArrayList of JSON Strings fetched from the internet.

```
public void updateListView(ArrayList<String> crimes) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> crimeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(),
                R.layout.listview_dbresults,
                R.id.listview_opendata,
                crimes);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dbResults);

        listView.setAdapter(crimeAdapter);
   }

@Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.

        try {
            URL url = new URL("JSON_LINK");
            Log.d("app", "url");

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            ArrayList<String> crimes = new ArrayList<>();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                crimes.add(line);
            }
            Log.d("app", "I've read all lines");
            return crimes;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> crimes)
        {
                if (crimes.size() == 0 || crimes == null) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return;
            }
            DataFetcher dataFetcher = new DataFetcher();
            dataFetcher.updateListView(crimes);
            }
```

The doInBackground is fetching JSON from an internet URL, it then passes it in to the onPostExecute and then calls the method from the DataFetcher class (a seperate class) to update the existing listview already in that class.

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference*
**Happens in my updateListView() method where the ArrayAdapter is instantiated.**

Comment: There is no `getSystemService()` call in your code snippet. Apparently you're losing your context somewhere.

Comment: So, how should I proceed? @SqueezyMo

Comment: What is the full stacktrace? Are you sure `this.getActivity()` does not return null for some reason when you're instantiating your adapter?

Comment: @SqueezyMo Yes! When I log this.activity() it comes back as null. What do I do here?

Comment: It depends on where you run your `AsyncTask`. Make sure it doesn't happen before `onActivityCreated` callback.

Comment: I think you should use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your updateListView method and use setListAdapter(adapter) in the onActivityCreated() method.

Comment: public void notifyDataSetChanged () -  Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()